# What branch of mathematics involves finding functions?

Tags: terminology, regression-analysis

Let's say we have an expression

$y = f(x)$.

- To find $y$ use arithmetic
- To find $x$ use algebra
- To find $f$ use regression

Is this correct? Or is there a better term than regression?

Comment: Interpolation, perhaps?

Comment: It depends rather what you mean by $f$ - if you have the corresponding values of $x$ and $y$ you already have the function specified by those pairs of values. Are you looking for a convenient expression for $f$, or a function $f$ with a convenient expression which approximates the values you are given, or something else?

Comment: @AlexJohnson: I would argue that  regression is a more general term since it include extrapolation as well, but Im not sure if there is an even broader term

Comment: @MarkBennet I just need a general term for finding functions/relationships of  dependent and independent variables

Comment: But what data are you given and what form do you want the answer to take? Does solving differential equations fall in your definition, or calculus of variations (finding functions which have maximum or minimum values - eg paths along which a journey takes least time). When you tag regression it looks like you are approximating data points with a nice function, but is that what you mean? And one definition of a function is a set of ordered pairs - so if you have that, one answer is that you already have a function. The question is too broad at the moment to have a single answer.

Comment: If you know all of the pairs of $x$ and $y$ then you don’t need to run a regression; you can explicitly define the function to give you the corresponding $y$ for each $x$! Regressions are only useful when you don’t have all the information about the pairs of $x$ and $y$, and importantly also won’t really tell you the shape of a function, it will just best-fit a particular shape to the given data.